# in Dart Editor keyboard shortcut for HTML comments

Tags: dart, dart-editor

What is the keyboard shortcut for HTML comments in Dart Editor?

I have tried Ctrl+/ but this only appears to work on dart source code

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a comment/uncomment keyboard shortcut for html files, but feel free to add a feature request at [dartbug.com/new](http://dartbug.com/new). Thanks!

Comment: I have submitted a bug report